# With statement in python is returning None object even though __init__ method works

Tags: python, with-statement

For a DB class with the following **init** method:

```
class DB:
    def __init__(self, dbprops):
        self.dbprops = dbprops
        self.conn = self.get_connection(self.dbprops)
        debug("self.conn is %s" %self.conn)

    def __enter__(self):
        pass
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        if not self.conn is None:
            self.close()
```

And for a client method invoking it as follows:

```
with DB(self.dbprops) as db:
    if not db:
        raise Exception("Db is None inside with")
    return db.get_cmdline_sql()
```

The output shows the debug message - thus the *init* method was successfully called:

```
  File "./classifier_wf.py", line 28, in get_cmdline_mysql
      raise Exception("Db is None inside with")
```

Exception: Db is None inside with

Update:  fixed the **enter** method to return a DB object . But need help on how to invoke it:

```
  def __enter__(self, dbprops):
    return DB(dbprops)
```

Invoking it with a single parameter does not work apparently:

```
 with DB(dbprops) as db:

TypeError: __enter__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Now I do not follow because the "self" is supposed to be filled in automatically..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [context manager protocol](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#context-manager-types) is handled by the `__enter__()` and `__exit__()` methods; the former must return the value to assign.

Comment: i see.  How do i avoid code duplication between the __init__ and the __enter__  after all not all clients will use "with": they may instantiate directly

Comment: assignment of the connection (conn). i.e. where should it be done (preferably only one place)

Comment: Why do you need to do it anywhere else but in `__init__()`?

Comment: that IS Where it is being done presently. so then your answer about the _enter_ no longer seems to be a difference maker: if it is then please explain further. - it was already in place (i added that content to the OP since it was neglected)

Comment: **"... must return the value to assign."**

Comment: *facepalm* `def __enter__(self):` `return self`